# Videos which are converted in Linux do not play in mobile browser

Tags: video, android, ffmpeg, avconv

I used `avconv` and `ffmpeg` to convert video files, but these files after this process did not work on a mobile browser. They only work as well on VLC or any other browser of desktop (Linux or Windows).

And I just used all of codes for conversion seen in the StackOverflow!
MP4 or WebM using H264 or VP9 codec do not work.

The last code which I used is this:

```
ffmpeg -i buck.webm -b 1500k -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -g 30 "example.mp4"
```

Works fine on a PC, but does not work in a mobile browser (Chrome or Firefox).

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: On your mobile device what happens if you are trying to play HDready, full HD Quad HD...  
That is can your device play our favorite formates?
If not try to encode in a smaller formate!!

Comment: Am I mistaken in believing that x264 and webm don't mix?  Normally x264 uses an mkv container while webm... well [webm only supports webm video codec (VP8 VP9)](http://www.webmproject.org/docs/container/).

Comment: You should show the complete console output from your command.

Comment: The mobile device play as well all videos converted in mac with the same especifications and mime-type.

The complete output is a long text to put here, but don't return any error.

even  a basic example of converting from avconv, the video who are made with it don't works.

Answer (score 7):

Have a close look at this document for android developers:

[Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Note that this gives only baseline settings and  any given mobile device might provide support for additional formats or file types not listed in the table.

Based on this it looks like your choice of *video* codec and settings for this codec are acceptable but you would be better to specify aac for the *audio* codec in your commandline. This would hopefully allow for a wide range of devices with successful playback.

A suggested commandline for FFmpeg would be:

```
ffmpeg -i input \
        -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 \
        -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 \
        -movflags +faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p \
        -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k \
        output.mp4
```

Some points for this choice of commandline:

1. For the greatest compatibility with a wide range of devices [it is recommended](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#AdditionalInformationTips) to use `-profile:v baseline -level 3.0`
2. It is an idea to add `-movflags +faststart` if your file is going to be displayed online, with this setting it should start playback *before* fully downloaded
3. Use `-pix_fmt yuv420p` to allow playback on a wider range of devices
4. `libfdk_aac` gives better AAC sound than the native FFmpeg AAC encoder (when this encoder was still marked 'experimental')

I have provided a working sample [here](http://www.andrews-corner.org/downloads/android_test.mp4) for testing purposes using this command line; and I note that this file works perfectly with my Google Pixel 3a (Android).

Comment: I already used AAC codecs and VP8 and VP9 video codec and the problem still here.

i just used the codecs used before in the program who i'm used in Mac.

Comment: Hmmm.... my understanding of that page is that you should be safe using h.264 with baseline profile and aac sound. Can you load a small sample of one of your converted files somewhere? I will produce one on my own system, upload it, and see if this will make your device happy...

Comment: http://www.irdeb.ba.gov.br/xaxado/videos/file.mp4 

http://www.irdeb.ba.gov.br/xaxado/videos/lindinho.mp4

http://www.irdeb.ba.gov.br/xaxado/videos/output.mp4

Comment: I used a lot of combination of command, but the last one ofmy script it's this:

avconv -i "/home/web-tec/Jobs/lindinho/arquivo.mov.MP4" -strict experimental -preset veryslow -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 1200k -crf 27 -profile:v baseline -vf "setsar=1:1" -s:v 720x480 -ar 44100 -ac 1 -acodec aac -b:a 160k -movflags faststart /home/web-tec/Jobs/lindinho/daa.mp4

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful but this do not solved my problem.



I used the same code that you sent and just dont works as well in mobile.

http://www.irdeb.ba.gov.br/fabiob.mp4

ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -movflags +faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k fabiob.mp4

Comment: I tested in firefox for mobile, the video starts and stop with the message:

Video can't be played because the file is corrupt

Comment: I am sorry, that pretty much reaches the limits of my knowledge in this area, Hopefully somebody cleverer than me can help you...

Comment: Thank you for the code, it was  a server problem!

I asked for a friend in my job, he solved this, thank you very much!

Comment: Good to hear that all has been resolved :). If the 'lowest common denominator' FFmpeg syntax I have given has been useful at all consider accepting my answer as well... And have a great day!

Comment: You can use the built-in encoder as well: `-c:a aac`